# NSTextAlignmentJustified throws error

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is the code:-

`lblValue` is an instance of UILabel.

```
[lblValue setText:@"Some Big String"];
[lblValue setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentJustified];
```

Error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'textAlignment does not accept NSTextAlignmentJustified'`

Comment: NSTextFieldAlignement works only with iOS6. If you're targeting iOS5 or iOS4.3, it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using iOS6 then `UITextAlignment` is deprecated. You can [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or you can use some 3rd party attributed Labels with fine alignment for this purpose.

**UIKit**

> NSString drawing additions and UILabel do not support NSTextAlignmentJustified orNSTextAlignmentNatural text alignments. Instead, use NSAttributedString drawing additions, which do support text alignments.

**[From UILabel Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)**

> If you are using styled text in iOS 6 or later, assigning a new value to this property causes the text alignment to be applied to the entirety of the string in the attributedText property. If you want to apply the alignment to only a portion of the text, create a new attributed string with the desired style information and associate it with the label. If you are not using styled text, this property applies to the entire text string in the text property.

Comment: I am using NSTestAlignment not UITextAlignment

Comment: You should created an attributed String for setting alignment for that purpose.

Comment: could you show me some sample code to achieve that?

Comment: What is your target version of iOS?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: did you read the question?

Comment: Yes I have read.. did you even read the answer properly???

Comment: UIKit

Notes

NSString drawing additions and UILabel do not support **NSTextAlignmentJustified orNSTextAlignmentNatural text alignments. Instead, use NSAttributedString drawing additions, which do support text alignments.** making it bold so you can read it.

Comment: ur answer is what my question!! I have tried that and its not working! therefore the question!

Comment: Thats alright, but could you show me some sample code?

Comment: read carefully the above comment and read through the answer and you will find somewhere `NSAttributedString` if you can not then use the search options.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28649/discussion-between-burhanuddin-sunelwala-and-nsgulliver)